# Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, phpstorm

I'm a total beginner to PHP so please forgive my ignorance.

I'm using PhpStorm to run a PHP Script. Every time that I execute my program, I get this error:

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php-7.4.1 -S localhost:3306 -t /path/to/project

Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Feb 18 02:07:07 2020] PHP Deprecated:  Directive 'track_errors' is deprecated in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Feb 18 02:07:07 2020] Failed to listen on localhost:3306 (reason: Address already in use)
```

I looked the exception up and found that `track_errors` is deprecated as of PHP 7.2.

The solution for this was to uncomment/delete the section about `track_errors` so I did although it didn't fix the error.

I'm clueless so thanks in advance

Comment: Did you restart the web server after changing the `php.ini` file?

Comment: Why are you starting a php script listening on the same port as the standard mysql one? Only one process can listen to a specific port number at once.

Comment: Running your PHP script on the MySQL port is almost certainly a mistake.

Comment: Are you sure you edited the correct configuration file? PHPstorm may be using a different one than you expect.

Comment: I also didn't see a change after I edited php.ini. Turned out my ini had a couple different sections with track_errors. I could be you haven't found all instances of the directive.

Answer (score 9):

In `php.ini` you can try changing

```
track_errors=On
```

to

```
track_errors=Off
```

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this message myself, when running `php --version`. When I looked in `/usr/local/etc` I discovered that my `php.ini` was several years old, while the other `php*` files were no more than a few weeks old. I was able to resolve the error message by

```
sudo mv php.ini php.ini.old
sudo cp php.ini-development php.ini
```